# Fetching list of files from the directory, but only subset filtered by date

Tags: c#, directory

Can I, using DirectoryInfo or even with some external API, fetch files from the LARGE directory (10s thousands of files) filtered by creation date (for example to fetch only the files created TODAY).

I am asking that because fetching the all files using

```
di.GetFiles("*.wma")
```

last for 10 seconds or more, and I have to use it repeatedly to scan for new files.

`FileSystemWatcher` is out of the question, as I learned that one does much better without it.

EDIT:

Memory is not the problem, the situation is that I have to know what are the files in directory at the given moment.  I can't reduce the number of files, but it seems that `FindFirstFileEx` might be some kind of a solution, if it works as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `GetFiles` try using `EnumerateFiles` - neither one has a date filter, but the enumerate version should cause less memory pressure as results will only be retrieved one at a time during iteration.

You may want to investigate the use of the [windows search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Search#Programmability) API - as far as I know it allows date constraints on searches, so should be suitable.

The real solution is not to have so many files in one directory.

Answer (score 0):

If the DirectoryInfo isn't fast enough for you and you're just looking at a few pieces of meta data, it may be faster for you to read all of the files once, gathering the metadate you need, then storing it in memory in a Dictionary collection, so you can peform whatever operatinos you want to on it.